# How to connect to socket.io in c#?

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I want to connect to socket.io server on nodejs using C#
This is the code i'm using

```
var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000/");
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () => 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connect");
});

socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (data) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
});
```

But the event **EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR** is always raised.
I tried to use browser, and it's working.
Here is the output:

> Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
>   ---> 
>       System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
>       System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>       at Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Transports.PollingXHR.XHRRequest.b__6_0()
>       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Thread.EasyTimer.TaskRun(Action action)
>       at Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Client.Transports.PollingXHR.XHRRequest.Create()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

This is the server code in typescript:

```
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
import { createServer, Server } from 'http';

class App {
    public io: SocketIO.Server;
    private server: Server;

    constructor() {
        this.io = socketIo(this.server);
    }

    private middleware(): void {
        this.io.on('connection', () => {
            console.log('a user connected');
        });
    }

    private routes(): void {
        let router = express.Router();

        router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
            this.io.emit('connection');
            res.json({
                message: 'Hello World!'
            });
        });
        this.express.use('/', router);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the server code?

Comment: @w0051977 I've added the server code

Comment: the default port number for a web server is 8080 not 3000.